# PHP mkdir creating duplicate folders

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm trying to automatically create folders with information from a database and for some reason even though both of the iterations have the same value it's creating an extra folder instead of putting the files in the same one.  I've commented everything out in the script but this line, and it is still doing it, so I know it's the culprit.  Here's my code:

```
if (!is_dir($state."/".$county."-County")) {
    mkdir($state."/".$county."-County");
}
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

The folder structure looks like this:

```
California
    Alameda-County
    Alameda-County
```

It's exactly the same.

Comment: is the casing different? `MyFolder` and `myFolder` and `myfolder` are completely different names on some Operating Systems.

Comment: Can you perhaps attach a screenshot or a list of the files/directories to help clarify the question?

Comment: `it's creating an extra folder` what is the name of this extra "folder" also if the `state` folder does not exist you will get an error, you should use the recursive flag if you are not sure its there, `mkdir($path, null, true);`

Comment: I added the generated folder structure to the original post.  It is definitely identical.  I'm dumbfounded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you **SURE** that both calls have the EXACT same values? There's many characters that LOOK the same but are fundamentally different internally. If you want to be sure you're using the exact same values, then don't do the path-building operation twice. Do it once:

```
$path = $state . "/" . $county . "-County";
if(!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}
```

Comment: No sense. You **can not** create entry as dir if it already exists as **file**

Comment: You should also foce a case to `$state` and `$country` like this: `ucfirst(strtolower($state))` and `ucfirst(strtolower($country))`

Comment: They are definitely the same exact values.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Oh my gosh I can't believe I did that.  I was casing, but I wasn't trimming.